# Unable to find vcvarsall.bat while installing PyAudio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, python-3.5, python-3.6, pyaudio

I want to make a tkinter application in which I should give commands on microphone to navigate the application. While trying to `pip install pyaudio` it shows an error `unable to find vavarsall.bat`. I have visual studio 2017 installed. After seeing some video I have added **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build** in environmental variable path. But still it shows that problem. I have installed visual studio with c++ to compile pocketsphinx and sphinxbase. I can't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Assuming you installed c++ support you should have a shortcut in your start menu for a developer command prompt. Open that and run pip inside it.

Comment: For VS 2015, it's in the VC directory, not the VC\bin directory:  \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC . For VS 2017, it's probably in the ...\VC directory as well.